# How to select from multiple tables based on condition

Tags: java, sql, activejdbc, javalite

I have two tables:

post table:

```
+-----+------------+--------------+
| id  |   title    |   details    |
+-----+------------+--------------+
| 185 | some title | some details |
| 186 | some title | some details |
+-----+------------+--------------+
```

post category:

```
+----+------------+---------+
| id |  category  | post_id |
+----+------------+---------+
|  1 | some title |     185 |
|  2 | some title |     186 |
+----+------------+---------+
```

When the user clicks on category, I want to get all posts from `post table` based on category selected.

I am able to select `category` and `post_id` like this:

```
List<Map> postCategories2 = Base.findAll("select category, post_id from posts_categories where category = ?", request.queryParams("category_name"));
```

But what I want is to use a single query and select `id, title, details` from `post table` using the `category and post_id` from table 2 i.e `category table`

All the information I have is category name i.e `request.queryParams("category_name")`

Note: `id and post_id` have primary key-foreign key relationship

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` the tables together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use a join for that
Replace your query with this query

```
select title,details,category from post p inner join posts_categories c on 
 p.id=c.post_id where category= ?//your category name at the question mark
```

hope this helps

Comment: I don't have `category` in post table. Also what does  'c' mean in `posts_categories c` ?

Comment: I have actually use join . category is the name of the column and c is just the object of posts_categories table just to not write the name of that table again and again.  I have actually fetched title and details from post table and category from post_categories table